# Gtest failed when catkin_make run_tests. Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, googletest

Somehow my `catkin_make` successfully executed but run_test failed. I have confirmed that I added my test script and my code as executable in CMakeList.txt and linked them using `target_link_libraries`. However, I keep getting the error when running `Catkin_make run_tests`:

```
undefined reference to `VisualRobot::VisualRobot(std::shared_ptr<moveit::core::RobotModel>)'
```

Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#include <eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <cmath>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "visual_robot.h"

class Checksweep : public testing::Test{
public: 

  virtual void SetUp() {
    // ...
    robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader("robot_description");
    robot_model::RobotModelPtr kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
    visual = new VisualRobot(kinematic_model);
  }

  virtual void TearDown() { delete visual; }

  VisualRobot * visual;
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

};

TEST_F(Checksweep, TestnJoint)
{
  EXPECT_GT(visual->nJoints, 0); //nJoints is a public variable in VisualRobot class.
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_testnode");
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And my visual_robot.h:

```
#ifndef _VISUAL_ROBOT
#define _VISUAL_ROBOT

class VisualRobot{
public:
    VisualRobot( robot_model::RobotModelPtr kinematic_model);
    void make_function();


    robot_model::RobotModelPtr kinematic_model;
    int nJoints;

private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher marker_pub;

};

#endif
```

In my understanding, I thought I already defined an instant of Visual Robot in my test code's line `VisualRobot * visual`

Edit 1: Also, it seems like the error occurs in my test code's line:

```
visual = new VisualRobot(kinematic_model);
```

Edit 2: Added part of my CMakeList.txt:

```
add_executable(visual_robot src/visual_robot.cpp)
target_link_libraries(visual_robot ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)

  find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
  add_rostest_gtest(visual_testnode launch/visual.launch src/visual_test.cpp )
  target_link_libraries(visual_testnode ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 --coverage")
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. The source of the answer is here:
[enter link description here](https://answers.ros.org/question/223005/cmake-error-trying-to-link-target-to-libraries/)

Basically, in my CMakerList.txt, I need to `add_library(visual_robot src/visual_robot.cpp)` 
and link it with my test file by using `target_link_libraries(visual_testnode visual_robot ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`